# InnerHTML or InnerText for outputting html tags as is

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use `innerHTML` or `innerText` to output a HTML basic document. I am making a website tutorial so I am trying to output the HTML tags as is... I can provide code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.textContent` instead so that characters with special meaning in HTML are not interpreted as HTML.

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
pre.textContent = `<div>Some content</div>`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Can I use a variable here... A multiline one to be exact?

Comment: @pyweb2434 Yes, you certainly can.

Comment: Is there a way to separate the code like it should be (`</HTML>\n<body>`) without `\n` because if you use `\n` then there is too much space!

Comment: @pyweb2434 Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/hy02rqt9/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225424/discussion-between-pyweb2434-and-iota).

Comment: Look in the chat!

Comment: Please look in our chat! or go to (https://web-tutorials.talinsharma.repl.co/html.html) and click the <!DOCTYPE HTML> button.